# Why does using `unknown` type to represent types that I don't mind instead of `any` induce a type checking failure?

Tags: typescript, generics

Given the following exercise:

```
type MyReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: unknown[]) => infer R ? R: never

/* _____________ Test Cases _____________ */
import type { Equal, Expect } from '@type-challenges/utils'

type cases = [
  Expect<Equal<string, MyReturnType<(v: boolean) => string>>>,
  Expect<Equal<123, MyReturnType<() => 123>>>,
  Expect<Equal<ComplexObject, MyReturnType<() => ComplexObject>>>,
  Expect<Equal<Promise<boolean>, MyReturnType<() => Promise<boolean>>>>,
  Expect<Equal<() => 'foo', MyReturnType<() => () => 'foo'>>>,
  Expect<Equal<1 | 2, MyReturnType<typeof fn>>>,
  Expect<Equal<1 | 2, MyReturnType<typeof fn1>>>,
]

type ComplexObject = {
  a: [12, 'foo']
  bar: 'hello'
  prev(): number
}

const fn = (v: boolean) => v ? 1 : 2
const fn1 = (v: boolean, w: any) => v ? 1 : 2
```

Even though the following types are inferred properly as I hover them,

`MyReturnType<(v: boolean) => string>`,

`MyReturnType<typeof fn>`,

`MyReturnType<typeof fn1>`

`Expect` generic does not evaluate true. The rest except the above types are correctly identified.

Lastly, if I replace `unknown[]` with `any`, it is resolved again.

The implementation of `Equal` of the library seems correct to me.

```
export type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false
```

Could you help me to figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that functions are **contravariant** with respect to the type of their parameters. Let's take a look at just the parameter types:

```
// true
type Args = [boolean] extends unknown[] ? true : false;
```

`[boolean]` extends `unknown[]`, great! Now let's put these in a function type:

```
// false
type Args = ((...args: [boolean]) => void) extends ((...args: unknown[]) => void) ? true : false;
```

Uh oh! It's false now, even though all we did was wrap the parameter types in a function type! But wait, if we reverse it, we get true again?

```
// true
type Args = ((...args: unknown[]) => void) extends ((...args: [boolean]) => void) ? true : false;
```

What's going on here? The easiest way to explain this is to just imagine a scenario where we're doing this exact operation; assigning a `(...args: [boolean]) => void` to `(...args: unknown[]) => void`.

```
// type is the same as (...args: [boolean]) => void
const func = (arg: boolean) => console.log(arg);

function callWithRandomStuff(fn: (...args: unknown[]) => void) {
    fn(1, "hi", false);
}

callWithRandomStuff(func);
```

Do you realize what we just did? We are calling `func` with the wrong arguments! You cannot pass a function with narrower parameter types to something that expects a function with wider parameter types, since if you call the narrower function with arguments of a wider type, you just did something unsound.

This is why we have to use `any`. The purpose of `any` is to ignore the type system. If we use `any[]` here, we get `true`, as desired:

```
// true
type Args = ((...args: [boolean]) => void) extends ((...args: any[]) => void) ? true : false;
```

If you need more information on covariance and contravariance in TypeScript, I recommend [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/) explaining what it is and why types behave the way they do. You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc/66411491#66411491) which briefly touches on covariance, contravariance, invariance, and bivariance (yes, there's more).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKFgFcBOA7AKuCAeTAfFALxSZQQAewE6AJgM5QAUAdOwIaoDmDAXFA7oQAbQC6AShJEAlugBmEVFHhQA-CqgD0EAG5KAUAdCQoAQR4MAjCSgiARgHtHAGwhCxFarUZRk6AGt0RwB3dHF1KGBUZGgBeQ4XBggAbmMcc0sAJltmNk5LAQdnNw8pYiJdRxk6KSoaeiY89lYuXgF-INDwyWkoKpqpDWjYrSgEpNT00wteAGZc-NbCv0DgsPFyyurarwbfZoL2uydXd3Reiv6doaiYuPHE5LSTaFmmUkPl4+Kzsr6Brt6j4mks2vxBMJNgCbpERg8Js8jAB6ABUUAA+ljsTjsWQIAxgFAAMIcZJMXGUrFQVHIgwyAC2YEcqCJrygAG8oABRACOyESABoeZRIABjIkAX3GqEcDKgAHIAAKvAC0YoAFok3OhuATkchgDIkgqjOzyKQ4IgUBhsJBcMxdAJTqV0FsoITUHJuAQzRkxWSCbYRAYoCLxcBcHyBS5cJ7vcKrUg0FgcA6nVAXed3fHdQR84LQ+GIBKo-zErgrFk5omEMnbWnmO6q3N8wRC2HuaKS5HoxXiXKwG5KAB5ewAKx7tetKbteCbfQHTOHY8nErbHeLpb7sYACrKGTJkrgs0J27A6zbU-aF1d93Kj3hT+g2+2i12I2WYw73Qr5M4FWnetr3nd1byIP8AI3d9u23ctYxsAAfKAsiAq851wV5HHkcYXwLGDPx3SsoGQ1CLxnBt7SwnD5HQKxoLEP1TCXIcqFXHtbA5IsOCKKthUgxwFUYsN7C4AQFQ1CAXBcQSizAVA9CbbRkAZexDElIwxUcdBCVw3IM2fd1dEiGwBCyAwtJ0olaJsT4DJKc5hRCAQhBAIyTLGLIgA)

Comment: Although I was knowledgeable about covariance and contravariance, it had never even crossed my mind that it was applicable here. I'm agonizing over whether the following contravariance in functions would pose a problem in any situations. Thank you for the great explanation.